# How can i find the general term for this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I determine the general term of the sequence below:

$\sqrt2, \sqrt{2\sqrt2}, \sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt2}},...$.

I've tried checking if it's some sort of geometric sequence, but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: Seems it is $$a_n=(2^{2^n-1})^{1/2^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Try writing every term of the sequence in expontial form with basis 2 and you will quickly see that the sequence is

\begin{equation}
2^{\frac{1}{2}},2^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}},2^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}},\ldots
\end{equation}

Thus, $x_n = 2^{\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{-i}}$. The exponent is a geometric series that converges to $1$. Since exponentiation is continuous, the sequence converges to $2$.

Answer (score 0):

The powers of $2$ follow the sequence $$\frac12, \frac34,\frac78, \frac{15}{16}...$$
So the nth term is $$2^{1-2^{-n}}$$